# How should I assume which iterator category an algorithm uses?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stl-algorithm

Let's say :

```
std::sort(beg1, beg2, pred);
```

This algorithm takes a range of iterators for the container and a predicate. It takes an LegacyRandomAccessIterator.
I do understand the the 5 iterator categories are categorised by their operators.
Albeit I'm having a hard time assuming which iterator the algorithm uses.

Comment: i dont understand the question. You already said it: " It takes an forward iterator." Though thats wrong. If you read [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) you'll see that `std::sort` requires LegacyRandomAccessIterator

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That was what I thought an example.

Comment: now that you edited the question to include the correct answer the question makes even less sense. Questions should not contain the answer

Comment: Doesn't the **name** of the template parameter already tell you what iterator it is?

Comment: The algorithm doesn't know anything about "the container". It operates on a **sequence**, designated by a pair of iterators. That's all that it knows. Yes, the data in the sequence is often held inside a container, but there are other ways of creating sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to assume anything, it is all documented. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) the iterators are `LegacyRandomAccessIterator`.

> **Type requirements**
> -RandomIt must meet the requirements of [ValueSwappable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ValueSwappable) and [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).
> -The type of dereferenced RandomIt must meet the requirements of [MoveAssignable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveAssignable) and [MoveConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveConstructible).

The page for [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) describes what such an iterator looks like.